# Get wrong time in Yii2-fullcalendar

Tags: php, yii2, fullcalendar

[image]

I don't know why the minute of start and end time on tooltip are different from calendar's time.
On the tooltip, the minute is always "05". Please help me to get correct value of minute (1:00 - 2:30).

This is code of fullcalendar widget:

```
<?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
            'options' => [
            ],
            'clientOptions' => [
                'allDaySlot' => false,
                'selectHelper' => true,
                'eventClick' => new JsExpression($JSEventClick),
                'dayClick' => new JsExpression($JSDayClick),
                'eventMouseover' =>new JsExpression($JSDayMouseover),
                'eventMouseout' =>new JsExpression($JSDayMouseout),
                'defaultView' => 'agendaWeek',
                'header' => [
                    'center'=>'prev,next today',
    //                'left'=>'title',
                    'left'=>'',
                    'right'=>'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
                ],
            ],
            //'events'=> $events,   // Dung khi goi action index
           'ajaxEvents' => Url::to(['/datsan/jsoncalendar', 'id_sanCon' => $modelSanCon->id])
        ));
        ?>
```

This is code for tooltip:

```
$JSDayMouseover = <<<EOF
    function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
       var tooltip = '<div class="fullcalendar-tooltipevent">'
                        + '<h3>'+calEvent.title+'</h3>'
                        + '<p>'
                        + calEvent.start.format("DD/MM/Y") + ': ' + calEvent.start.format("HH:MM") + ' - ' + calEvent.end.format("HH:MM")
                        + '</p>'
                        + '</div>';
        $("body").append(tooltip);
        $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
            $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
            $('.fullcalendar-tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
            $('.fullcalendar-tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
        }).mousemove(function(e) {
            $('.fullcalendar-tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
            $('.fullcalendar-tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
    });
    }
EOF;
```

web.php

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 05 you see on the minutes is actually the month date (May).
You have a formatting bug.
Change the MM to mm in the minutes format:

```
 var tooltip = '<div class="fullcalendar-tooltipevent">'
                    + '<h3>'+calEvent.title+'</h3>'
                    + '<p>'
                    + calEvent.start.format("DD/MM/Y") + ': ' + calEvent.start.format("HH:mm") + ' - ' + calEvent.end.format("HH:mm")
                    + '</p>'
                    + '</div>';
```

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA. I see. Thank you!